# i'm having Referenceerror with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```js
const {connect, connection} = require('mongoose');

connect( 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/socialNetwork',
    {
        userNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
);

// use this to log mongo queries being exectuted!

mongoose.set('debug', true);

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: What's the exact error??

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `userNewUrlParser` and `useUnifiedTopology` if you are using Mongoose v6+.

Try only this:

```
connect( 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/socialNetwork);
```

Comment: yes i removed it but still comes with the same error.